# Uploading images with Store Manager

Tags: multistore, import, image, image-upload

I have a task of trying to use store manager to upload images as part of a large import for a new store we are creating,

However the import I run does not upload the images correctly,

I have been following -https://www.mag-manager.com/useful-articles/magento-product-management/import-images-with-store-manager-for-magento/

but the images do not appear as they should, the result of magento back end is - [image: Images result on backend after image import]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check image size. It may overcome allowed image dimensions that's why pictures do not display. Below in the admin you can see the message about it.
2. Check FTP task queue in the application. All images you upload to Magento are being added to queue and uploaded one by one. If there are lots of images they may still be uploading and you will see them afterwards when the upload completes.
3. Make sure you enabled "Regenerate image name" option if one and the same images is being added to several products. Magento 1.9.1 and up requires image name regeneration.
4. Make sure you have enabled "Import images" checkbox in Store Manager import wizard (Fields Delimiter and Additional Settings step)